# how to remove default constraint from column in Db2

Tags: sql, db2, default-constraint

I had a table STUDENT_TB, which had column STUDENT_ID, NAME, AGE. I added a column with a following command :-

```
alter table STUDENT_TB add DOB TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP
```

as for the DOB column i didn't wanted it to be null. Now i need to remove that default constraint.

I tried searching but not got any success.

Regards.

Comment: Please clarify if you are attempting to remove the `NOT NULL` constraint, or the `DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP` clause.  Please note that DB2 (and I believe all DBMS's) will _always_ place some sort of default, even if that is `null` - the initial wording of the question makes it appear that you want no default to be placed.  You don't specify the flavor, but likely the inherent default (what happens if `default` is not specified) will by the current timestamp if the column is not nullable (`null` if it is).

Comment: i need to remove the default constraint.. anyways i tried one thing and that worked.. will post soon..

Comment: Okay, looks like I was wrong: specifying `NOT NULL` but _not_ `DEFAULT` causes (at least on the iSeries version) the system to throw an error on insert (if that column is not given a value).  Specifying _neither_ is an implicit `DEFAULT NULL`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried with this and it worked properly

```
alter table STUDENT_TB alter DOB drop DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 2):

ALTER TABLE STUDENT_TB ALTER COLUMN DOB DROP NOT NULL